# Passing cookie using cURL

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I realize that this has been covered a bunch of times but for some reason it's still not working for me. I'm trying to pass a cookie to a page via cURL but the destination page still won't pick it up.

Relevant code below.

```
        $cookie = "did=1";
        $ch = curl_init();
    $cj=tempnam("/","cookiejar");
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1;       en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13')" );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try using something like

```
$ckfile = tempnam ("/", "CURLCOOKIE");
```

here's sample way to do it

```
<?php
$ckfile = tempnam ("/", "CURLCOOKIE");

$ch = curl_init ("http://somedomain.com/");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);

$ch = curl_init ("http://somedomain.com/cookiepage.php");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);

/* here you can do whatever you want with $output */
?>
```

**EDIT**

```
class CURL {
var $callback = false;

function setCallback($func_name) {
$this->callback = $func_name;
}

function doRequest($method, $url, $vars) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
if ($method == 'POST') {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
}
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if ($data) {
    if ($this->callback)
    {
        $callback = $this->callback;
        $this->callback = false;
        return call_user_func($callback, $data);
    } else {
        return $data;
    }
} else {
    return curl_error($ch);
}
}

function get($url) {
return $this->doRequest('GET', $url, 'NULL');
}

function post($url, $vars) {
return $this->doRequest('POST', $url, $vars);
}
}
?>
```

got it from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php)

Comment: thanks for the response - is the CURLCOOKIE going to the cookie or the filename holding the cookie?

Comment: And also, what is the syntax to use for a cookie file. Would it just be "CookieName=CookieValue"?

Comment: it would be like curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt'); where this is the cookie file

Answer (score 0):

This is example how to work by cookies by curl,and take care about it,that you should have write permission to do it.
    http://curl.phptrack.com

```
$url = "http://curl.phptrack.com/login.php"; // URL
$POSTFIELDS = 'name=admin&password=guest&submit=save';
$reffer = "http://curl.phptrack.com/index.php";
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)";
$cookie_file_path = "C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/spiders/cookie/cook"; // Please set your Cookie File path. This file must have CHMOD 777 (Full Read / Write Option).

$ch = curl_init();  // Initialize a CURL session.     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  // The URL to fetch. You can also set this when initializing a session with curl_init(). 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); // The contents of the "User-Agent: " header to be used in a HTTP request. 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); //TRUE to do a regular HTTP POST. This POST is the normal application/x-www-form-urlencoded kind, most commonly used by HTML forms. 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$POSTFIELDS); //The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  // TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly. 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // TRUE to follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header (note this is recursive, PHP will follow as many "Location: " headers that it is sent, unless CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS is set). 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reffer); //The contents of the "Referer: " header to be used in a HTTP request. 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); // The name of the file containing the cookie data. The cookie file can be in Netscape format, or just plain HTTP-style headers dumped into a file. 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); // The name of a file to save all internal cookies to when the connection closes. 

$result = curl_exec($ch);  // grab URL and pass it to the variable.
curl_close($ch);  // close curl resource, and free up system resources.

echo $result; // Print page contents.

?>
```